# Math.round bug - what to do?

Tags: c#, .net, rounding

`Math.Round(8.075, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)` returns `8.07`, though it should return `8.08`. Mysteriously enough, `7.075` is working fine, but `9.075` also returns `9.07`!

What to do? Does anybody know a rounding method without such bugs?

Comment: I'm very doubtful .net would have such bugs, if that is what is happen then I'm sure it was implemented that way for a reason.

Comment: You can use a decimal type as they are more precise: `Math.Round(8.075m, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)`

Comment: we need Jon Skeet here

Comment: Ahh, I forgot to mention that Eric Lippert just wrote a great blog post about rounding: http://ericlippert.com/2013/05/16/spot-the-defect-rounding-part-two/

Comment: @Jasd: it's not that decimals are more *precise*, though they are. It's that decimals have zero representation error *if the desired quantity is a fraction with powers of five and two in the denominator*. doubles have zero representation error *if the desired quantity is a fraction with powers of two in the denominator*. Since 8075/1000 has a power of 5 in the denominator even in lowest terms, it gets representation error in a double.

Answer (score 12):

If you count with 10 fingers, like humans do, you don't have any trouble expressing the decimal value 8.075 precisely:

```
  8.075 = 8 x 10^1 + 0 x 10^0 + 7 x 10^-1 + 5 x 10^-2
```

But computers count with 2 fingers, they need to express that value in powers of 2:

```
  8.075 = 1 x 2^3  + 0 x 2^2  + 0 x 2^1  + 0 x 2^0  + 0 x 2^-1 + 0 x 2^-2 + 0 x 2^-3 + 
          1 x 2^-4 + 0 x 2^-5 + 0 x 2^-6 + 1 x 2^-7 + 1 x 2^-8 + 0 x 2^-9 + 0 x 2^-10 +
          1 x 2^-11 + ...
```

I gave up with finger cramp typing the terms but the point is that no matter how many powers of 2 you add, you'll *never* get exactly 8.075m.  A similar problem to how humans can never write the result of 10 / 3 precisely, it has an infinite number of digits in the fraction.  You can only write the result of that expression accurately when you count with 6 fingers.

A processor of course doesn't have enough storage to store an infinite number of bits to represent a value.  So they *must* truncate the digit sequence, a value of type double can store 53 bits.

As a result, the decimal value 8.075 gets rounded when it is stored in the processor.  The sequence of 53 bits, converted back to decimal, is the value ~8.074999999999999289.  Which then, as expected, gets rounded to 8.07 by your code.

If you want 10 finger math results, you'll need to use a data type that stores numbers in base 10.  That's the System.Decimal type in .NET.  Fix:

```
decimal result = Math.Round(8.075m, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

Note the usage of the letter m in the 8.075m literal in the snippet, a literal of type decimal.  Which selects the Math.Round() overload that counts with 10 fingers, previously you used the overload that uses System.Double, the 2 finger version.

Do note that there's a significant disadvantage to calculating with System.Decimal, it is **slow**.  Much, much slower than calculating with System.Double, a value type that's directly supported by the processor.  Decimal math is done in software and is not hardware accelerated.

Comment: That's why *real* mathematicians [count using 60 fingers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexagesimal).

Answer (score 5):

I am not a .net specialist, but these numbers can't be exactly represented as double, so the rounding is accurate if you take into account the real value of those 3 numbers:

```
7.075 ==> 7.07500000000000017763568394002504646778106689453125
8.075 ==> 8.074999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875
9.075 ==> 9.074999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875
```

More about floating-point precision: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: How did you find the real values?

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko With a java program, but I suppose you can do the same in .NET.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko: I have a C# program for that here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/17/looking-inside-a-double.aspx  and a recent follow-up post here: http://ericlippert.com/2013/05/13/spot-the-defect-rounding/

Answer (score -1):

The possible solution might be:

```
(double)Math.Round((decimal)8.075, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```