# Rounding to 4 decimal places - Unexpected results

Tags: c#, .net, rounding

When rounding I'm getting the following outputs:

```
Math.Round(2.3234503,4) = 2.3235

Math.Round(2.323450,4) = 2.3234
```

I can't see how this makes sense, can someone point it out to me? I expected an answer of 2.3235 both times. How can the number 3 or lack of in the last decimal place affect the outcome?

Comment: I don't believe it is, i know the default is to round to even instead of rounding away from zero but if you look again at the example ive shown here it demonstrates a different issue

Comment: Because of the 03, you're not halfway anymore. You're slightly *above* halfway.

Comment: The question marked as duplicate is not relevant here. The value `2.323450` is *not* a tie, so it doesn't matter whether round-ties-to-even or round-ties-away-from-zero is in use. The value in the second example from the OP is slightly closer to `2.3234` than to `2.3235`, thanks to binary floating-point. (The actual value stored is `2.323449999999999793232063893810845911502838134765625`.)

Comment: Better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621832/math-round-bug-what-to-do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/zy06z30k(v=vs.110).aspx)

Returns:

> The number **nearest** to d that contains a number of fractional digits
>   equal to decimals.

Key word is nearest.

2.3234 503 - nearest to 503 is 5 so rounded to 5

2.3234 50 - is half way.

In half way from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.math.round(v=vs.110).aspx)

> In a midpoint value, the value after the least significant digit in
>   the result is precisely half way between two numbers. For example,
>   3.47500 is a midpoint value if it is to be rounded two decimal places, and 7.500 is a midpoint value if it is to be rounded to an integer. In
>   these cases, the nearest value can't be easily identified without a
>   rounding convention. The Round method supports two rounding
>   conventions for handling midpoint values:
>
> **Rounding away from zero**
>
> Midpoint values are rounded to the next number away from zero. For
>   example, 3.75 rounds to 3.8, 3.85 rounds to 3.9, -3.75 rounds to -3.8,
>   and -3.85 rounds to -3.9. This form of rounding is represented by the
>   MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero enumeration member. Rounding away from
>   zero is the most widely known form of rounding.
>
> **Rounding to nearest,or banker's rounding**
>
> Midpoint values are rounded to the nearest even
>   number. For example, both 3.75 and 3.85 round to 3.8, and both -3.75
>   and -3.85 round to -3.8. This form of rounding is represented by the
>   MidpointRounding.ToEven enumeration member. Rounding to nearest is the
>   standard form of rounding used in financial and statistical
>   operations. It conforms to IEEE Standard 754, section 4. When used in
>   multiple rounding operations, it reduces the rounding error that is
>   caused by consistently rounding midpoint values in a single direction.
>   In some cases, this rounding error can be significant.
>
> **By default, the Round method uses the rounding to nearest convention.**

Comment: The OP is asking why the *half-point* number rounds down instead of up. That's not the *nearest* number. .NET is using round-to-even, often called Banker's Rounding. That's the IEEE 754 standard

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you are right, answer improved

Comment: Thanks for your input. My mistake what that I believed if you round to say 4 decimal places that you took the 5th number and applied the tie break rule. I did not know that you took all the remaining digits (i.e. 503) and applied the rule

Comment: round-to-even is irrelevant here. The closest representable `double` value to `2.323450` is *not* a half-way case; it's slightly below the halfway value.

Comment: You mean slightly above, right?

Comment: @user48408: I'm fairly sure I mean below. :-) The exact value that's stored is `2.323449999999999793232063893810845911502838134765625`, which is sightly below the halfway value `2.32345` that acts as a threshold for the ties-to-even and ties-away-from-zero rounding methods. That's why it ends up rounding down.